# NODEJS process info

Tags: node.js, process

How to get the process name with a `PID` (Process ID) in Node.JS program, platform include Mac, Windows, Linux.

Does it has some node modules to do it?

Comment: http://nodejs.org/api/process.html  simply `process.pid`

Comment: Isn't this API is the only access to the PID I want additional information is obtained by the PID

Comment: process also gives you platform, arch, memory usage, cwd, etc. What other info do you want?

Comment: Do you want that information for your own Node process, of for other processes?

Comment: @pianist829: Check the updated answer. particular with respect to your needs. Please let me know once you tested it...Works only one windows but you can change to other OS cmd with same logic

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Yes, built-in/core modules `process` does this:

So, just say [`var process = require('process');`](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_pid) Then

To get PID (Process ID):

```
if (process.pid) {
  console.log('This process is your pid ' + process.pid);
}
```

To get Platform information:

```
console.log('This platform is ' + process.platform);
```

**Note:** You can only get to know the PID of child process or parent process.

---

Updated as per your requirements. (Tested On `WINDOWS`)

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var yourPID = '1444';

exec('tasklist', function(err, stdout, stderr) { 
    var lines = stdout.toString().split('\n');
    var results = new Array();
    lines.forEach(function(line) {
        var parts = line.split('=');
        parts.forEach(function(items){
        if(items.toString().indexOf(yourPID) > -1){
        console.log(items.toString().substring(0, items.toString().indexOf(yourPID)));
         }
        }) 
    });
});
```

On `Linux` you can try something like:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
    cmdd = spawn('your_command'); //something like: 'man ps'

cmdd.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log('' + data);
});
cmdd.stderr.setEncoding('utf8');
cmdd.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
  if (/^execvp\(\)/.test(data)) {
    console.log('Failed to start child process.');
  }
});
```

Comment: To get `PID` you should use `process.pid`, but not `process.getgid`.

Comment: You're not required to require("process"), it's a global variable already avaiable. https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process

Comment: use ==> if (items.toString().search('\\b' + yourPID + '\\b') > -1) instead of if(items.toString().indexOf(yourPID) > -1). Because this give true if the 'yourPID' is match in the item other than PID ( eg: it will be true if that is match in memory slot)

Answer (score 14):

On Ubuntu Linux, I tried

```
var process = require('process'); but it gave error.
```

I tried without importing any process module it worked

```
console.log('This process is your pid ' + process.pid);
```

One more thing I noticed we can define name for the process using

```
process.title = 'node-chat'
```

To check the nodejs process in bash shell using following command

```
ps -aux | grep node-chat
```

Comment: In your last example, I think you are mixing Javascript with bash.

Comment: The require is not more required ! See https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/process.html#process_process_pid

Answer (score 9):

cf official documentation  https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/process.html#process_process_pid

the **require** is no more needed.
The good sample is :

```
 console.log(`This process is pid ${process.pid}`);
```

Comment: awesome easy one line way to get process id in node.js thanks!