# Get current assigned process id in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to get current process id which is currently used.I'm using cluster for multiprocessing. I need this because I want to kill child process after the use to reduce memory utilise but I only get the current process Id when I call `process.exit()` method. But I don't want to call `process.exit()` method in each route and `cluster.on('exit')` couldn't called.

Answer (score 1):

Process PID can be accessed by `process.pid`.

Answer (score 1):

Node has several global methods and attributes, one of them being `process` which holds the current node process info.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

##### built-in/core modules process does this :-

```js
const process = require('process'); // On ubuntu, you dont need this (if there is an error)

if (process.pid) {
  console.log('This process is your pid ' + process.pid);
}
```

---

**Another answer from stackoverflow :-** [**NODEJS process info**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15474682/14781260)

Comment: I've used this but this will work when I start server but when I call any route its not working . so is there any way to get process id all time when I hit endpoints.

Comment: so you are saying that you can't access the `process.pid` in your router ?!

Comment: I can but I have to kill current process which are used by route and I don't want to add  `process.exit()` method in route to call `cluster.on('exit')` method and I want to kill current process id. so do you have any example for cluster implementation with route. my question is related to cluster sorry for title.